# Perl DBI - Loading into SQL Serverl

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, load, dbi

I have to load a text file into a database on a daily basis that is about 50MB in size. I am using Perl DBI to load the file using insert statements into a SQL Server. It is not very performant, and I was wondering if there are better/faster ways of loading from DBI into SQL Server.

Comment: You don't say how the file is processed, but SQL Server has a decent ETL tool - I think they call it Integration Services these days.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use the [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement.  No reason you couldn't run that from DBI.

Answer (score 1):

When doing large `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations, it's generally useful to disable any indexes on the target table(s), make the changes, and re-enable the indexes.  This way, the indexes only have to be rebuilt once instead of rebuilding them after each `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statement runs.

(This can also be applied in a zero-downtime way by copying the original table to an unindexed temp table, doing your work on the temp table, adding indexes, dropping the original table, and renaming the temp table to replace it.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to speed things up (if not already done) is to use [prepared statements and bind-values](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Outline_Usage).